# Ionic3 Angularfire listen to firestore changes

Tags: angular, ionic3, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

how do I listen to event after firebase cloud function had successfully updated a document? Because there is a few seconds lag while the function is running. I want to implement a loading screen and dismiss it when the function successfully updated the record.

example:

1. MyApp update data to firebase ref A
2. firebase function detect changes in ref A and execute update same data to ref B
3. MyApp does not know when will firebase function complete step 2 above, i need to listen to ref B for changes done to dismiss the loading

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `update` or `set` method of Angularfire to change the value of a document. those methods return a  `Promise`, when fulfilled you can remove hte loader.

```
updateItem() {
    this.loading = true;
    const item = { id: 1, name: "My Item };
    this.db.doc('item/1').update(item)
                         .then(() => this.loading = false;;
}
```

For more exmaples look at the [angularfire documents documentation](https://github.com/angular/angularfire2/blob/master/docs/firestore/documents.md)

Update:

If you need to subscribe to document changes without changing it, simply do:

```
this.db.doc('item/1).valueChanges()
                    .subscribe((data) => console.log('new data logic');
```

Comment: thanks, due the update is not done on my main APP code, its done by the firebase function. my main APP need to listen to changes from the firestore and dismiss the loading.

Comment: You can use `valueChanges` of `FireStoreDocument` in order to execute some code when the document has updated

Comment: yes i know about valueChange. i can use async pipe in html to update the changes. but what command do i call if i want to detect the changes in my TS file? 
from your answer above
this.db.doc('item/1).valueChanges()
                    .subscribe((data) => this.name = data.name;
can i wait for the name to change to 'Eric' to dismiss the loading?
if(this.name == 'Eric'){ loading.dismiss()}

Comment: You put any logic you want inside the subscription block